# Scrapy: Check MongoDB for duplicates before crawling

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I'm crawling all news from the **first page** of over 50 news websites on a daily basis and storing them in a MongoDB database. I'm using the news URL as `_id` as a unique identifier. Some websites take significantly longer than others to crawl. To speed up my crawling process, I need to go through my database first before crawling the newly extracted URLs.

I don't want to use `persistent support` as it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Also, as shown below, I have written a duplicate filter but it only helps with a single crawling session, and the data is gone after each process termination.

Here's what my `pipeline.py` looks like:

```
class DuplicatesPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self.urls_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        if item['_id'] in self.urls_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.urls_seen.add(item['_id'])
            return item


class MongoDBPipeline:

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(
            mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
            mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE')
        )

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
        self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.client.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.db[spider.name].insert_one(dict(item))
        logging.debug("Article added to MongoDB")
        return item
```

I need to extract the URLs first. Then go through the database `_id`s to see if the extracted URLs already exist and only then can I start crawling.

Is there an easier way to do this? If not, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to check the database to get all previously crawled URLs to prevent duplicates and improve performance by roughly 50%. I used a [guide](https://blog.dipasquale.fr/en/2018/12/17/incremental-scraping-with-scrapy-and-mongo/) written by  Adrien Di Pasquale and got some ideas. Here's what my spider looks like after modification. Also, as suggested in the article `pipeline.py` was slightly modified.

```
class BBCSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'bbc'
    allowed_domains = ['www.bbc.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.bbc.com/news/',
        'https://www.bbc.com/news/world/us_and_canada',
    ]

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('https:\/\/www.bbc.com\/news\/world-us-canada-[0-9]+$'),
                                deny=('https:\/\/www.bbc.com\/news\/av\/.*')),
                  callback='parse_item',
                  process_links='filter_links')]

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['mongo_uri'] = crawler.settings.get("MONGO_URI")
        kwargs['mongo_database'] = crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE')
        return super(BBCSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri=None, mongo_database=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BBCSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mongo_provider = MongoProvider(mongo_uri, mongo_database)
        self.collection = self.mongo_provider.get_collection(self)
        # URLs that have already been scraped in previous crawling sessions
        self.scraped_urls = self.collection.find().distinct('_id')

    def filter_links(self, links):
        # Removes URLs that have already been scraped in previous crawling sessions
        for url in self.scraped_urls:
            for link in links:
                if url in str(link):
                    links.remove(link)
        return links

    def parse_item(self, response):
        if response.status == 200:

            item = SmartCrawlerItem()

            item['_id'] = response.url
            item['title'] = response.css('title::text').get()
            item['date'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="story-body"]//ul[@class="mini-info-list"]//div/text()').get()
            item['article'] = response.css('div.story-body__inner>*::text').getall()

            if None in item.values():
                return
            else:
                item['date'] = get_unique_date(item['date'])
                item['article'] = clean_response(item['article'])
                yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [scrapy-deltafetch](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-deltafetch) package to ignore requests to pages (urls) seen in previous crawls of the same spider.

Comment: While the link shared may answer question, it is always encouraged to give full details with proper codes and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Storing all the previous data in memory feels like a bad idea as when scale goes up this will come back to bite you in the ass.

You have many possible work arounds. It seems to me that the easiest approach is just to re-write `process_item` to check for duplicates before insert.

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
        exists = self.db[spider.name].find_one({"_id": dict(item)["_id"]})
        if not exists:
            self.db[spider.name].insert_one(dict(item))
            logging.debug("Article added to MongoDB")
        return item
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem with this is that I want to reduce the crawling time which is crucial as some websites take significantly longer than usual to crawl. Therefore, it's important to me that nothing is crawled twice. As for the memory, I assume it would not have that much of an impact as it's gonna scale up to less than 100,000 URLs in my case which is no that large to fit in memory.